# How to have a automatic id generation in view page?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi I am using codeigniter I have a view page with a simple form where I get few information about items purchased.
All the item purchased is needed to be saved in table with same id. For example

```
-+------+-----------+
 +  Id  + Items     +
 +------+-----------+
 +  1   +  iphone6s +
 +------+-----------+
 +  1   +  ipad     +
 +------+-----------+
```

Here with same id I need to generate a bill and close this view page. When another purchase open then my next id must change to 2 automatically.
So that all other purchased id until bill generation will be 2 and next will be 3 so on.. How to do this? Can someone help me?
Please give me some solution. Thanks in advance

Comment: So there is Java in it?

Comment: you get max from the Id column and save it in session.

Comment: java means? @HawasKaPujaari

Comment: How to get do that? @SagarKhatri

Comment: Oh.. I have no idea about this concept. Can you give me some solution? @HawasKaPujaari

Answer (score 0):

you should have 2 tables.

A table, lets say, 'bills' for keep track of your bills.

A table, 'bills_items', for your bill's items.

'bills' should have a PK autoincrementing that generates a new ID for each inserted record (a bil).

each time you insert a bill on it you can get the newly created id into a variable like `$idvar = created id with mysql_insert_id(...)`

Then you insert all items of that purchase in 'bills_items' using the
value of `$idvar` as the id

check http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Comment: Can we have this code in controller where I insert my bill?

Comment: if it is PHP you chould be able to use `mysql_insert_id()` it right after the line that actually inserts a record.

Yet, we don't know your controller

Comment: Along with my form? or dealing with database? @Julio Soares

Comment: this is database stuff... data comes from your form but the issue is on how you store it... right?

Comment: Yes and also when I create a second bill I need to display the current Id  in my form that I need to store

Comment: you never know your ID until right after you insert it.
So you can't show it before actually creating the bill.

Comment: mysql_insert_id() gives the last inserted id? But for the first time how the id will be set? @Julio Soares

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90670/discussion-between-julio-soares-and-anu).